# How to package a WPF (.NET Core) app with XamlIslands and Desktop Bridge?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge, xaml-islands

I have an application in `WPF` targeting `.NET Core v3.1` and I'm using `XamlIslands` to display Windows 10 UI components. In order to use `XamlIslands`, I had to first migrate my app from `.NET Framework` to `.NET Core`.

I put my custom `UWP` components into a `UWP project`, which targets `Win10 version 2004`, min version is `1903`. And in the `WPF` project I can reference these custom `UWP` components using [XamlHosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/windowsxamlhost).

Then, I have a `Desktop Bridge` project, which can package the `WPF` application, to be able to upload to the Microsoft Store.

The project compiles and runs correctly, I can run even the packaging project, but when I try to create a sideloaded App Package, it gives me the following error:

```
Project UWP is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / win-x64. Project UWP supports: uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362)
Project UWP is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project UWP supports: uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362)
```

I tried to set the min version for the `UWP` app to `windows 10, build 10240` (this is the oldest one), but the same error appeared (of course, with the updated uap version).

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55477211/6607702) answer I read that maybe I should create a `.NET Standard` project? But there is no way to create a `WPF` application targeting `.NET Standard`.

1. How the error message says that the `UWP` app is not compatible with `.netcore` when I could build and run the whole solution? If it runs, why can't create an App Package?
2. How can I create an App Package then, which I can upload to the Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to package a WPF (.NET Core) app with XamlIslands and bridge?

Please refer [Host a custom WinRT XAML control in a WPF app using XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands) official document. And derive from your information, it looks you have not configured your solution to target a [specific platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands#create-a-wpf-project) such as x86 or x64. Custom WinRT XAML controls are not supported in projects that target Any CPU.
And please don't forget edit your wpf project [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands#add-a-reference-to-the-uwp-project-in-your-wpf-project)

```
 <AssetTargetFallback>uap10.0.19041</AssetTargetFallback>
```

I have make a [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Islands-Samples) and I could make the package base on above steps, here is official code sample, you could download it and test to make a package.

Comment: Ooh thank you so much! I had just the x64 and x86 platforms in every project, but the `AssetTargetFallback` was missing from the config file. Adding it, solved the problem :)